# Proving that $X_n= 2^n 1_{(0,\frac{1}{n})}, n \geq 1 $ converges to zero in probability

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems

**Let $\Omega =[0,1],$ the sigma algebra: $F=B(\mathbb{[0,1]})$ and $\mathbb{P}=m$ (Lebesgue measure)
$X_n$ is a random variable: $X_n= 2^n 1_{(0,\frac{1}{n})}, n \geq 1 $**

**Prove directly, that is,  using the definition, that $X_n \overset{p}\to 0$**

The definition of convergence in probability states that If $X, X_n$ are random variables   $\forall \varepsilon \geq 0, \mathbb{P}(|X_n| > \varepsilon) \overset{n \to \infty}\to 0$

**My lecture notes give this short proof, that I am struggling to understand:**

$\forall \varepsilon \geq 0, \mathbb{P}(|X_n| > \varepsilon)=\mathbb{P}(X_n=2^n)=\mathbb{P}((0,\frac{1}{n}))=\frac{1}{n} \overset{n \to \infty}\to 0$

I don't understand how they go from $\mathbb{P}(|X_n| > \varepsilon)$ to $\mathbb{P}(X_n=2^n)$ to $ \mathbb{P}((0,\frac{1}{n}))$. I trying to separate it into cases according to the value of $\varepsilon$, but I have to consider that the indicator function eventually becomes zero for sufficiently large n and at a fixed $\omega \in \Omega$. Can someone explain it in detail?

Answer (score 1):

Notice that for a fixed $n \in \mathbb{N}$,  $X_n(\omega) > 0$ if and only if $\omega \in (0, \frac{1}{n})$. Thus for any $\epsilon > 0$, $P(|X_n| > \epsilon)= P((0,\frac{1}{n})) = \frac{1}{n}$.

Edit: changed $x$ to $\omega$ to make notation a bit clearer

Comment: what is $x$ here? Is it a value of $X_n$?

Comment: @mathlover I've edited my response so that it's a bit clearer. Recall that $X_n$ is a function from the sample space $\Omega$ to the interval $[0,1]$. So $\omega$, or $x$ in my original post, is the input of the function.

Comment: All right, but still what I don't get is how the probability of$ |X_n| > \epsilon$ transforms. $\omega$ is  suppossed to be fix and n is supposed to be varying like in a sequence of functions, and when it does, eventually $\omega$ falls outside the intervall $(0, 1/n)$ , so$ X_n=0$. When $\omega$ falls inside the intervall $(0, 1/n)$ i still have $P(2^n> \epsilon)$ and shouldn't I work it from there?

Comment: Let me break it down more: $P(|X_n| > \epsilon) = P(X_n = 2^n)$, since $|X_n| > 0$ if and only if $\omega \in (0, \frac{1}{n})$, and thus $X_n(\omega) = 2^n$. Similarly, $P(X_n = 2^n) = P((0,\frac{1}{n}))$ because $\{\omega \in \Omega | X_n (\omega) = 2^n\} = (0, \frac{1}{n})$. Obviously, $P((0,\frac{1}{n})) = \frac{1}{n}$. Thus $P(|X_n| > \epsilon) = \frac{1}{n}$ for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Taking the limit of both sides as $n$ tends to infinity gives you the result you want.

Comment: This one $P(|X_n| > \varepsilon)=P(X_n=2^n)$ is still giving a hard time. There is an epsilon there $|X_n| > \varepsilon$ that you are not using. Let me explain how I see it: First $\varepsilon$ is a "roof" one fixes and when want the probability that $X_n$  goes over the roof. This should happen for a certain $n_0$ if the intervall $(0, 1/n)$ that is shrinking  still contains $\omega$  so in that case $ P(|X_n| > \varepsilon)=P(2^n >\varepsilon)=P(n>log(\varepsilon))$...for $\omega <1/n$ and I don't know what to do from here,

Comment: Besides as n continues to increase, the interval continues to shrink and $\omega$ falls outside eventually, giving $ P(|X_n| > \varepsilon)=P(0> \epsilon)=0$ . This also happens if the roof epsilon is small enough so that initially no value of the $X_n$ goes over the roof

Comment: I'm implicitly assuming $0 < \epsilon < 1$, which is fine since we only care about what happens for small $\epsilon$. Since $2^n > 1$ for $n\geq 1$, we have that $|X_n| > \epsilon$ if and only if $X_n = 2^n$. I think what's getting you stuck is the idea that the interval $(0, \frac{1}{n})$ is shrinking. You don't want to take this into account until you start taking a limit. Remember that $P(X_n = 2^n)$ is the probability measure of the set $\{\omega \in \Omega | X_n(\omega) = 2^n\}$.

Comment: So the intervall is fixed then, what about $\omega$, is it fixed as well? It could fall outside the intervall and we would have $ 0$ probability.The definition should  also be verified for big $\varepsilon$, since it is given$ \forall \varepsilon$, but then all the trouble I described arises